# Error of Loading data from base in a DropDownList ASP MVC 3 and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.
I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.
I have created a 'DropDownList' to load a data from a table of my base.
But as result, this DropDownList show me : **'NameofApplication.Models.NameofTable'**
I don't know why ? 
This is the declaration of the DropDownlist in the view :

```
<%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%>
<%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Gamme", String.Empty) %>
```

And this is the Controller of Profile_Ga :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Controllers
{ 
    public class ProfileGaController : Controller
    {
        private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();

        //
        // GET: /ProfileGa/

        public ViewResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga)
        {
            ViewBag.ID_Gamme = new SelectList(db.Profil_Gas, "ID_Gamme", profile_ga.ID_Gamme);
            return View(db.Profil_Gas.ToList());


        }
```

and Finaly this is the model :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Profile_Ga
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "ID Gamme:")]
        public string ID_Gamme { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Gamme Entrante:")]
        public string In_Ga { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Gamme Sortante:")]
        public string Out_Ga { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Gamme Suivante:")]
        public string Next_Gamme { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Etat:")]
        public string Etat { get; set; }
        }
}
```

PS : 
Name of table in the base is Profile_Ga

Comment: With your last comment below then my very first answer is correct. Try and do that please. So you should have `return View(db.Profil_Gas.ToList());` in your controller method and `<%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Gamme", new SelectList(Model, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme ")) %>` in your view. Remember that your Model is a collection of `Profile_Ga`.

Comment: Cool, finally, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a collection of `Profile_Ga`, I think you meant to use that

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Gamme", 
    new SelectList(Model, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme ")) %>
```

Although that looks not correct at all. In your method you did this

```
public ViewResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga)
{
    ViewBag.ID_Gamme = new SelectList(
        db.Profil_Gas, "ID_Gamme", profile_ga.ID_Gamme);
    // did you plan to return a single instance here
    // and use that as your model
    return View(single_instance_of_Profile_Ga );
}
```

then your view would look like this

```
// then you can declare the dropdown like this
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ID_Gamme, (SelectList)ViewBag.ID_Gamme) %>
```

**UPDATE** (from comments)

> Thx, "you want to show a list that you got from your database into
>   your view"--> yes this what I want what

```
public ViewResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga)
{
    // you need to decide if you want to use this
    // ViewBag.ID_Gamme = new SelectList(
    //     db.Profil_Gas, "ID_Gamme", profile_ga.ID_Gamme);
    // or this
    // return View(db.Profil_Gas.ToList());
    // but since it seems you are confuse to what you are doing
    // then I suggest you just do this
    // this will return a collection model to your view
    return View(db.Profil_Gas.ToList());
}
```

then in your view you need to do this

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("ID_Gamme", SelectList(Model) %>
```

> do you intend to do with that dropdown --> I want when I choose an
>   item,,,a pop up appears. The loading of Data is always false,,,why i
>   will edit

You need to edit your question because you did not ask that initially. So my question for you is what will the popup have, an edit form perhaps? You need to ask a new question because you will have to explain it, I have to answer, you have to ask question in comments and it will be a long chat - SO won't like that. It'd a new issue anyway and asking a question is free ;)

Comment: Thanks, also,,,i try it this but the statement is underlined in Red and the error is :
System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplicati‌​on2.Models.Profile_Ga>>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Ah right, that's the downside of using Viewbags. You need to cast it to a `SelectList`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Your solution is right, but another error appears now lol,
ID_Gamme is underlined in Red and the error is :
Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.Profile_Ga>' does not contain a definition for 'ID_Gamme' and no extension method 'ID_Gamme' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.Profile_Ga>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please read my answer again, there's actually a question there (in the code comments). You cannot use the dropdownlistfor if you are returning a collection. Use the first one I gave `Html.DropDownList("ID_Gamme", (SelectList)Model)`. But you have to think about what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Sorry Von v if if I bother you,,,but i am really stuck and I am beginner with ASP MVC.
I change like you told me but this error appears :
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MvcApplication2.Models.Profile_Ga', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApplication2.Models.Profile_Ga]'.
I try to put this : <% Html.RenderPartial("PrfileGa", Model, new ViewDataDictionary()); %>
But Nothing !!

Comment: No worries. I think your question clearly states that "you want to show a list that you got from your database into your view". Doing my first suggestion will do that - to avoid confusion stick to that. Your next question would be, what do you intend to do with that dropdown? Will that accept an input and be posted back? If yes then edit your question and include the relevant codes and the updated question. Or better yet, create a new since a different (although related) issue anyway. And also, we will be running out of "comment space" here if in case you have other questions about it.

Comment: Thx, "you want to show a list that you got from your database into your view"--> yes this what I want<br/>
'what do you intend to do with that dropdown' --> I want when I choose an item,,,a pop up appears.
The loading of Data is always false,,,why i will edit ?

Comment: See my updated answer. Please pay attention to it, it's not advisable that we have this long conversation here.

Comment: Thanks,,,This is will be my last comment (because as you said, it's not advisable).
I am just need to clarify my problem because when i read your update, I find that you understand me wrong ( or rightly ,,i explain ou wrong).
So, I want to show the list in my view and I did that with success in a table. But also, below the table , I want a DropDownList that contains only The ID_Gamme